# Bootstrap - Have items display as block in two column layout rather than split over two columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have created a bootstrap accordion like in this snippet and styled it into two columns.

However, when I expand a section I want to try keep each `.card` as a block so its not expanding over two columns.

Any ideas or suggestions on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated.

Adding `display:block;` to `.card` has no effect.

```css
#accordion {
  column-count: 2;
}

.card {
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Heading1</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading2">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">Heading2</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading3">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">Heading3</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading4">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse4">Heading4</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse4" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading4" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading5">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse5" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse5">Heading5</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse5" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading5" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading6">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse6">Heading6</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse6" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading6" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: whether u want to display all the headings one by one (each heading occupying full width)?

Comment: If you want full width accordion just need to remove `#accordion{column-count:2;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside).

```css
#accordion {
  column-count: 2;
}

.card {
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  break-inside: avoid-column;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="accordion">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading1">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse1">Heading1</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse1" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading1" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading2">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse2">Heading2</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse2" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading2" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading3">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse3" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse3">Heading3</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse3" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading3" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading4">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse4" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse4">Heading4</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse4" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading4" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading5">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse5" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse5">Heading5</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse5" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading5" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header" id="heading6">
      <button class="btn" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse6" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse6">Heading6</button>
    </div>
    <div id="collapse6" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="heading6" data-parent="#accordion">
      <div class="card-body">
        <a href="#">item1</a>
        <a href="#">item2</a>
        <a href="#">item3</a>
        <a href="#">item4</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```